# Create a modal popup dialog in angular

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

I've a requirement to show popup dialog from angular component. For example, I want to show a message box and then want to get some confirmation from user based on say click of Yes, No, Cancel button in the message box. I want to perform action based on what button user has clicked. Can someone please help? I'm new to web development and angular.

Comment: can you please post a bit of code

Comment: You can use simple bootstrap popup or NG2BS3 modal. You will get plenty of examples available on Internet.

Comment: Use Sweetalert2 for angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use material angular popup & modal, here is great example: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples;

You must install `material` using `npm` or `bower`; for `npm` run this command: `npm install '@angular/material' --save`

then You can import necessaries into Your component like this: `import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';`

Answer (score 0):

---

it shows pop-up message with OK and Cancel Button. If you want to do anything while clicking on OK button or On Cancel Button.

```
import alertifyjs from 'alertifyjs';

showConfirmAlert(){
      alertifyjs.confirm('Are you sure want to cancel this transaction? You will lose any information entered.', 
      function (e) {
      if (e) {
      //Suppose you want to redirect to home page while click on OK Button
        window.location.href = "/home";
      }
      else
      {
      // code on clicking on cancel button
      }
  });}

<div class="col-3">
        <button (click)="showConfirmAlert()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-custom mr- 
        3">Button Name</button>
</div>
```

Or You can also follow below the another procedure ----

```
showConfirm(msg: any, onOkay: any, onCancel: any) {
alertifyjs.confirm('Confirm', msg, onOkay, onCancel).set('resizable', true);
}

showConfirmAlert(
this.showConfirm('Are you sure want to cancel this transaction? You will lose any information entered.',
  () => {
    //Suppose you want to redirect to home page while click on OK Button
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  },
  // code on clicking on cancel button
  () => { });
)

<div class="col-3">
    <button (click)="showConfirmAlert()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-custom 
    mr-3">Button Name</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm Sorry. I forgot.